# Minipage: Align text, image and caption

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, captions, align, minipage

I try to split my page into a text part on the left and an image on the right side. Therefore I use `minipage` and `flushright`.

There are 2 problems:

• I want to have the text and the image being top aligned. The minipage option `[t]` does not work unfortunately, neigther the try `\vspace{0pt}`.

• The image is right aligned properly, but the caption is not. It should be shifted to the right as well to be centered under the image again.

How can I achieve both? Thank you :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.38\textwidth}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.57\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image-9x16}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption\\Long Caption}
  \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Probably the following gets closer to the desired output. (Lines indicate margins):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %for the valign=t option
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.38\textwidth}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5.7cm}
  \begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[height=10cm, valign=t]{example-image-9x16}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption Long long Caption}
  \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Here is a version using `measuredfigure` from `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %for the valign=t option
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.38\textwidth}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.57\textwidth}
\hfill
  \begin{measuredfigure}
    \includegraphics[height=10cm, valign=t]{example-image-9x16}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption Long long Caption}
  \end{measuredfigure}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works quite well. But why can't I use the `\textwidth` but have to give a specific minipage width in cm?

Comment: @Max16hr: I decided to make the minipae just as wide as the image in order to get the caption centered under the image instead of being cantered with respect to the whole minipage.

Comment: Okay. I dont think, that this is the proper way to do so. But the top alignment works good, thank you! :)

Comment: @Max16hr: I have added an alternative version using the `measuredfigure` environment from the `threeparttable` package. Probably you like that version better.

Answer (score 2):

`paracol` is a good choice.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \lipsum[2]
  \switchcolumn
  \includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image-9x16}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption\\Long Caption}
  \switchcolumn*
  \lipsum[3]
  \switchcolumn
  \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-16x10}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption\\Long Caption}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]